# When do I need to cast a value as a date?

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm working myself through the Datacamp SQL track, and I'm currently working with date values. I've encountered two examples which seem contradictory to me.

```
    -- Count requests created on January 31, 2017
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM evanston311
 WHERE date_created::date='2017-01-31';
```

And:

```
-- Count requests created on February 29, 2016
SELECT count(*)
  FROM evanston311 
 WHERE date_created>= '2016-02-29' 
   AND date_created< '2016-03-01';
```

Why do I need to cast the value as date in the first case but not the other?

Comment: You don't need, but it will be better if you cast your strings to date always when compare with column of date type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most typed languages, you can rely on implicit type casting... until you can't.

Something like `date_created >= '2016-02-29'` Postgres can use the type of `date_created` to figure out how to implicitly cast `'2016-02-29'`. There's no ambiguity. But sometimes Postgres can't make a guess at all.

OTOH a function like `date_part` has multiple signatures `date_part(text, timestamp)` and `date_part(text, interval)`. If you pass it a date string...

```
test=# select date_part('day', '2019-01-03');
ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select date_part('day', '2019-01-03');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

...Postgres cannot make a guess because the second string could be interpreted as either a `timestamp` or an `interval` type. You need to resolve this ambiguity.

```
# select date_part('day', '2019-01-03'::date);
 date_part 
-----------
         3
```

Now that Postgres knows you're passing in a `date` it can correctly guess to use it as a `timestamp`.

---

Another reason is as a cheap way to truncate timestamps. In your example `date_created::date = '2017-01-31'` will truncate `date_created` to be a `date` and make the comparison work. Of course, `date_created` should already be a `date`...

You can use it on the value being compared if you're not sure if that value will be a date or a timestamp.

```
select * from table
where date_created = $1::date
```

This will work the same with '2019-01-02' or '2019-01-02 03:04:05'.

---

Which brings us to our final reason: making up for bad schemas. Like if `date_created` is actually a `timestamp`, or all too common, `text`. In that case you need to explicitly control how comparisons are made. For example, let's say we had `text_created` of type `text` that contained timestamps as strings: naught. And maybe some poorly formatted data crept in that has extra spaces on the end...

```
-- Text comparison compares the values exactly.
test=# select * from test where text_created = '2019-01-04';
 date_created | time_created | text_created 
--------------+--------------+--------------

-- Date comparison compares as dates ignoring the extra whitespace.
test=# select * from test where text_created::date = '2019-01-04';
 date_created | time_created | text_created 
--------------+--------------+--------------
              |              | 2019-01-04
```

See [Chapter 10. Type Conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv.html) in the Postgres docs for more.